# Index might not exist (textField) swift xcode

Tags: arrays, swift

Basically, the description is an optional input and will throw errors such as "invalid index range" when there's input such as "Grapes green". Is there a way through extensions or some other method besides adding additional text fields that would solve this issue?

```
let fruits = "\(textField.text!)"
let fruitsArray = fruits.split(separator: " ")
let fruitName = "\(fruitsArray[0])"
let fruitColour = "\(fruitsArray[1])"
let description = "\(fruitsArray[2])"
```

Comment: Although I think the question seems to be unclear, you should check the count of `fruitsArray` before attempting to access an element in it.

Comment: Also, what's the reason of adding three different points in the same textfield?!

Answer (score 0):

For such a case (still find it not so sensible to ask for three different properties in a single text field), I would suggest to implement a *template* for the `fruit` thing. Example:

```
struct Fruit {
    var name: String?
    var colour: String?
    var description: String?

    init?(string: String) {
        let array = string.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).components(separatedBy: " ").filter { !$0.isEmpty }
        switch array.count {
        case 3...:
            fallthrough
        case 3:
            description = array[2]
            fallthrough
        case 2:
            colour = array[1]
            fallthrough
        case 1:
            name = array[0]

        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

At this point, you are able to declare a `Fruit` instance by passing the string for it; Therefore:

```
let string = "Grapes green"
let fruit = Fruit(string: string)
print(fruit)
// Optional(__lldb_expr_21.Fruit(name: Optional("Grapes"), colour: Optional("green"), description: nil))
```